# how I can call variable in mappable class from main view

Tags: json, swift, objectmapper

I have three class one is the main view and here is the code of it

```
    class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            getJSONS().getLowerJSON()

            setupUI()

    }
 func setupUI(){
    print(lowerData.companyName)
}
    }
```

getsJSONS call an function that call almofire to handle json as in this code

```
class getJSONS {
func getLowerJSON(){

        let URL = "http://tickerchart.com/interview/company-details.json"
        Alamofire.request(URL).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<lowereViewResponse>) in

            let lowereViewResponse = response.result.value

        }

    }
}
```

lowereViewResponse call the mappable class  as in this code

```
class lowereViewResponse: NSObject, Mappable {
    var companyName :  String?
    var symbol : String?
    var tradesCount : Int?
    var high : Int?
    var low : Int?
    var volume : Int?
    var amount :  Int?

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    convenience required init?(_ map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }


    func mapping(map: Map) {
        companyName <- map["company-name"]
        symbol <- map["symbol"]
        tradesCount <- map["trades-count"]
        high <- map["high"]
        low <- map["low"]
        volume <- map["volume"]
```

}

```
    required init?(map: Map){
        companyName = ""
        symbol = ""
        tradesCount = 0
        high = 0
        low = 0
        volume = 0
        amount = 0
        price = 0
    }


}
```

all imports are done

I am trying to call class lowereViewResponse to access the variable but I get null when this is exited "print(lowerData.companyName)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use like following:

```
let lowereViewObject: lowereViewResponse = Mapper< lowereViewResponse >().map(JSON: result)
```

Comment: result gives my an error unresolved identifier , I've add it after  `Alamofire.request(URL).responseObject { (response: DataResponse<lowereViewResponse>) in`

Comment: at "result" at the end @Sujit

Comment: Here result is json value that you received, modify it according to your response dictionary name @OmarDiab